# How to derive the length of a string or an array from DWARF?

Tags: dwarf

For the following code, after being compiled by GCC, is it possible to derive the length of the "teststr" and "testarray" variables from DWARF?

```
void func(char *str1, char *str2){
     ...
     ...
     return;
}

int main(void){
     char *teststr = "123456";
     char testarray[6] = "123456";

     func(teststr, testarray);     
     ....
     ....

     return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DWARF is pretty much a representation of what the compiler knows about the source program.  So the general answer to this question is: if you can find the size "locally" in the source, then yes; otherwise no.

But in this case if we remove the `...`s from your program and compile it, we can just read the DWARF directly using `readelf`.

Here's what `testarray` in `main` looks like:

```
 <2><5c>: Abbrev Number: 3 (DW_TAG_variable)
    <5d>   DW_AT_name        : (indirect string, offset: 0x5): testarray
    <61>   DW_AT_decl_file   : 1
    <62>   DW_AT_decl_line   : 7
    <63>   DW_AT_type        : <0x7f>
    <67>   DW_AT_location    : 2 byte block: 91 60  (DW_OP_fbreg: -32)
...
 <1><7f>: Abbrev Number: 7 (DW_TAG_array_type)
    <80>   DW_AT_type        : <0x78>
    <84>   DW_AT_sibling     : <0x8f>
 <2><88>: Abbrev Number: 8 (DW_TAG_subrange_type)
    <89>   DW_AT_type        : <0x8f>
    <8d>   DW_AT_upper_bound : 5
 <2><8e>: Abbrev Number: 0
 <1><8f>: Abbrev Number: 6 (DW_TAG_base_type)
    <90>   DW_AT_byte_size   : 8
    <91>   DW_AT_encoding    : 7    (unsigned)
    <92>   DW_AT_name        : (indirect string, offset: 0x60): sizetype
```

That is, it is an array of 6 characters.  So in this case you can find the length -- exactly what you'd expect from reading the source.

However `teststr` and the variables in `func` look more like:

```
 <2><4e>: Abbrev Number: 3 (DW_TAG_variable)
    <4f>   DW_AT_name        : (indirect string, offset: 0xf): teststr
    <53>   DW_AT_decl_file   : 1
    <54>   DW_AT_decl_line   : 6
    <55>   DW_AT_type        : <0x72>
    <59>   DW_AT_location    : 2 byte block: 91 68  (DW_OP_fbreg: -24)
...
 <1><72>: Abbrev Number: 5 (DW_TAG_pointer_type)
    <73>   DW_AT_byte_size   : 8
    <74>   DW_AT_type        : <0x78>
 <1><78>: Abbrev Number: 6 (DW_TAG_base_type)
    <79>   DW_AT_byte_size   : 1
    <7a>   DW_AT_encoding    : 6    (signed char)
    <7b>   DW_AT_name        : (indirect string, offset: 0x7d): char
```

This says it is just a pointer-to-char -- in other words, the length isn't statically known.  A debugger like gdb can find the length at runtime by reading memory from the inferior, just like your program would have to.

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain how can we tell testarray is an array of 6 characters from the above DWARF info? If I guess it correctly, we can tell it from the "DW_AT_upper_bound". Then my question is if there are multiple arrays in main, how can we match different "DW_AT_upper_bound" with their corresponding array respectively?

Comment: It's all based on the type.  First you can find the entry for the variable `testarray` - DIE 0x5c.  Then look at the type of the array, DIE 0x7f.  The type is an array type, so look at the bounds.  The low bound is 0 (it isn't explicit but you can know it based on the CU's language) and the high bound is 5 -- so the length is 6.  Other arrays in the function would have their own types with their own bounds.